# Full Screen Mode in IE 11 for child window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am launching a child window in IE 11 using windows.open. In the child window there is a button on click of this the child window has to move to Full Screen mode. My child window has the canvas, and doesn't have any iframes. When i click on the full screen button the window is not moving to full screen where as it is giving an error saying " `“HTML5Viewer.js onCanvasFullScreenError”`

In IE I have tried all the methods like `requestFullScreen`/`msRequestFullScreen` for them also I am getting the below error.

```
document.msFullscreenEnabled
true
document.getElementById("xxxxxx").msRequestFullScreen();
Object doesn't support property or method ‘msRequestFullScreen'
```

Any help will be appreciated.